# Create custom command in Cypress containing asserting / chain commands

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-intercept

I wish to create a custom command that contains status code assertions:

```js
cy.wait('@interceptedEndpoint')
    .its('response.statusCode')
    .should('eq', 200)
```

the last two lines are what I want inside the custom command

```js
.its('response.statusCode')
.should('eq', 200)
```

My initial idea is below which obviously wouldn't work

```js
Cypress.commands.add('checkResponse', {prevSubject: 'element'}, () => {
    .its('response.statusCode')
    .should('eq', 200)
})
```

What am I missing above to make the custom command creation correct?

EDIT: In addition to Udo.Kier's answer. I needed to set `prevSubject` to **true** to make it accept the response for the expected assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding the `subject` parameter,

```js
Cypress.commands.add('checkResponse', {prevSubject: true}, (subject) => {
  cy.wrap(subject)
    .its('response.statusCode')
    .should('eq', 200)
})

...

cy.wait('@interceptedEndpoint').checkResponse()
```

Alternatively, with the wait inside the custom command:

```js
Cypress.commandsCommands.add('waitAndCheckResponse', (subjectAlias) => {
  cy.wait(subjectAlias)
    .its('response.statusCode')
    .should('eq', 200);
})

...

cy.waitAndCheckResponse('@interceptedEndpoint')
```

Comment: How do I use the custom command to chain into a `cy.wait('@anyAlias')`? It seems to not work when I try `cy.wait('@anyAlias').checkResponse()`

Comment: I didn't try it, but the `cy.wait('@anyAlias')` is supposed to yield an "interception" object which has `request` and `response` properties so logically this should succeed.

Comment: Yes, the `cy.wait('@anyAlias')` came from a `cy.intercept()` command. The error by the way is: `cy.checkResponseStatus() failed because it requires a DOM element. The subject received was Object{10}`

Comment: I was able to make it work. You are right about the error part. I changed it to `{prevSubject: true}`. It shouldn't be `'element'` since we are asserting a response from an intercept if I understood it correctly. But your edited answer is also a good option.

Comment: Ok, I missed that variation. If the `prevSubject` is removed altogether the yielded value is blocked from entering the custom command.

Comment: Is your second answer final? I'm not familiar with `cy.wrapwait()`

Comment: No, that's a mistake - thanks for pointing it out